# How can I update the chart in livechart based on array value with a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

i am currently using Livechart, Cartesian chart for my WPF c# program, based on the example given in the livecharts website. I have successfully manage to represent the value of the array onto the Cartesian Chart.

Below is the xaml code

```
  <Grid Margin="0,0,219.4,-0.2">
                        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="cartchartdb" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" >
                            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                                <lvc:Axis Title="Value" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
                            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                                <lvc:Axis Title="Date" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
                            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                        </lvc:CartesianChart>
                    </Grid>
```

Below is the code. for the Xaml.cs

```
 private void cartchartinit()
    {

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Avg Speed (KM/H)",
                Values = arrayspeedavg.AsChartValues()
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Avg Gap (Metre)",
                Values = arraygapavg.AsChartValues()                                                     
            },
            
        };

        Labels = datearray;
        YFormatter = value => value.ToString("");        
       
        DataContext = this;
        cartchartdb.Update(true);
    }
```

The problem now is I was not able to update the graph again when a new value is inserted into the array.*edit: The chart will only update if i restart the program.

My current idea is to put a button to refresh the chart but it didnt update.

Code for button update:

```
        private void refreshcart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        getvalueforgraphing();

        cartchartdb.Update(true);
    }
```

the `getvalueforgraphing()` is the function to update the array back with the new value inserted. The `cartchartdb` is the name for the lvc.CartesianChart tool.

Hope someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nvm got it!

basically my workaround is as shown below

```
        private void refreshcart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        getvalueforgraphing();

       // SeriesCollection[0].Values.Clear();
        SeriesCollection[0].Values = arrayspeedavg.AsChartValues();
        SeriesCollection[1].Values = arraygapavg.AsChartValues();
        Labels = datearray;

    }
```